# Hardcoding Arrays and Objects or populate from Database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, arrays, object

At the present moment I am putting together a product website for my company featuring about 80 or 90 unique products with various characteristics.

Initially, I hard-coded a multidimensional array to store the products and their various characteristics. Aside from being a lot of typing to set up it also felt like it would be challenging to update/maintain.

I also felt like I had a lot of spaghetti code elsewhere on the site, so I learned about OOP and refactored the site utilizing class structures and interfaces. Very nice and clean. Except, now I am faced with hard-coding objects, of which there are many.

I've done a lot of reading and know I can probably convert my array data into objects, but nonetheless the issue of maintenance keeps cropping up as some product characteristics may change frequently. My solution to this is to use a mysql database (which seems easier to maintain) and extract the product and characteristic data from there into objects.

My question is:

**Is this typically best practice? Are arrays/objects typically populated this way and it was crazy to hardcode it all in the first place?**

Apologize in advance for the newbie question. I have done a substantial amount of reading but haven't come across anything that gives the direct advice I'm looking for. My brain might be short-circuiting but I have not been able to synthesize it clearly from what I've read either.

Comment: Cannot imagine that you never heard about a database before!

Comment: @hek2mgl - I have, but think I received bad advice early on that storing data in arrays was a better route. Either that or I misunderstood the advice.

Comment: I don't know what you've heard, but this is usually done by a database.

Comment: thanks @hek2mgl, it just goes to prove that you should not believe everything you read on the internet, at least if you are not sure you're interpreting it properly, lol.

Comment: Yep.. Of course this can be done. And might be *a step* in a tutorial, but the final solution will use a database. You said it yourself: It gets messy to administrate when having code and data together.. Note that a database can be even a xml file.

Comment: Haha I had a 2nd question originally with regards to utilizing XML over a Database. Figured I'd narrow it to a database to learn the ropes and maybe XML later if it makes sense. Tons of Database vs. XML info out there so didn't want to get down voted for not having read it all yet.

Comment: Don't care too much about down votes. I see you are a relatively new user. After some time you'll get a feeling for *what is a good question and what is not* .. However, mostly questions that are easy to google or even easy to find using the stackoverflow search function will get down voted (or closed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case I would definitely refactor the existing code and put it on the database rails.

For refactoring purposes I suggest you to use model objects which can be populated either from database or from your hard-coded arrays using different adapters.

Rewrite your code with adding model objects to work with your business logic entities using existing data source (hard-coded array); and then change data source to the database.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the response. Not only did you give a solid recommendation, you provided a clear roadmap on how to achieve it that reinforces the principles of refactoring. Great advice for someone new to programming.

Comment: @mjs You are welcome! Read more about design patterns, they will help you to do effective refactorings of the existing code.

Answer (score 4):

If the only query you're ever going to run is `` SELECT * FROM `table`; ``, then you could use a hardcoded array. If you will be using ANY other query to access the data, then it should be in a database.

Comment: thanks, thats a very good guideline. So much information is on how to traverse arrays, do array to database conversions and vice versa, or performance/memory related that it's sometimes tough to find the baseline design/structure principles i.e. might be best to utilize x in y situations.